# Как узнать какую спецификацию JS поддерживает определённая версия Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Например в какой версии node данный код:

```
const factorial = (n) => {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return n * factorial(n-1);
  }
}
```

не вызовет синтаксической ошибки? А в какой его следует заменить на:

```
var factorial = function factorial(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
};
```

Comment: [Node.js ES2015 Support](https://node.green/)

Answer (score 2):

Стрелочные функции поддерживаются в Node начиная с версии 4.4.5.
Const - вообще с каких то 0.10.ых версий в strict mode.

Узнать можно в гугле ([тут например](https://node.green/))